# How can I make increasing list and matrix in Scheme?

Tags: list, scheme

I am trying to create an increasing matrix, but first I want to make increasing lists. Here is my procedure;

```
(define make-lst
  (lambda (a b)
    (if (= a 0)
        '()
        (list b
              (make-lst (- a 1) (+ b 1))))))
```

But it gives me the output;

```
(10 (11 (12 (13 (14 (15 (16 (17 (18 (19 ())))))))))) ;(make-lst 10 10)
```

How can I get a list like

```
'(10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19)
```

I am really beginner in Scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `(list 1 2)` makes a list `(1 2)` and `make-list` returns a list it is not strange that it makes the aoutput `(first (second (...)))`

Now `(list a b)` does `(cons a (cons b '())` and thus you can replace `list` with `cons` such that it takes one element and a tail and cons a list of that.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I got confused between cons and list, also how can I  get  (1 2 (3))  by using ony cons and nil?

Comment: @HARUNSASMAZ `(cons (cons 3 '()) '())` is `((3))` and `(cons 1 (cons 2 '((3)))` is `(1 2 (3))`. I see `(1 . (2 . ((3 . ()) . ())))` in my head when I look at `(1 2 (3))`